# Bluetooth Service Solicitation in Windows UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to my iPhone and access services such as the battery level and ANCS from windows. I have tried out the Advertisement watcher and query but I feel as though they are really inconsistent. I am just using the code they provided in their updated [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-low-energy-overview). I feel as though my results are extremely buggy. Devices show up multiple times and then become unreachable. It's almost as if past devices are never cleared from the cache (this may need to be something I do manually?) upon restarting my UWP in debug x86. I have briefly had success with the advertisement watcher and was even able to initiate pairing. Although when I read the battery level it was still not a number after using the data reader. I noticed that there were some service solicitation properties on the documentation but I could not figure out how to use them. Would these help and if so how could I use them? This might be useful when I try to connect to the ANCS of my iPhone.

Edit 1: After trying out the sample provided by Microsoft, I am still having a similar issue. I am able to see devices and even pair with them but when I click the connect button, it returns that there is a connection failure. In order to advertise to the BLE I am using the LightBlue app on my iPhone to advertise a virtual peripheral with the battery service added. My end goal is to connect to the iPhone directly and access some of its native BLE services and characteristics. I have heard that this can be done with something called service solicitation but have failed to successfully find any real examples of this being put into practice in a UWP (maybe it's not used anymore). I am still pretty new to BLE so I am trying to work out some of my fundamental misunderstandings of how it works so if there is something I am missing please let me know below!

[BLE Failing to connect after pairing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLC4x.png)

Edit 2: Ok after cleaning and re-building to fix some of my silly mistakes, I can now say that the example project is running as intended from what I can tell. The solution is actually pretty nice and I can see it is much more  elegant than my implementation. However, I see that I am running into the same issue as before where the services of my virtual peripheral become undiscoverable after pairing and now result in a "Device Unreachable" exception in scenario 2. It seems as though Windows does not support "Resolvable Random Private Addresses." To elaborate, it does not provide my phone with an Identity Resolving Key (IRK) upon pairing with my iPhone 11 in order to keep track of its address. In order to access certain key characteristics, I need authorization.

Is there any way I can exchange an IRK upon pairing using the custom pairing capability or is there another method to provide authorization in order to access these characteristics on my iPhone? As it is, ANY and ALL GATT services present on the iPhone (virtual peripheral or native OS) become unreachable **as soon as I successfully pair with the device**. I am hoping it is possible to implement a solution in Windows as if not then communicating meaningful data between modern devices seems impossible with outdated privacy protocols.

I did a little bit of research and it is either the problem above or something to do with my Bluetooth device.

[If I were to try to access characteristic without pairing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTmGt.png)

Edit 3: I have been able to get it to work briefly and it was wonderful. I used the system settings to pair and magically got the prompt on my phone to share notifications. From there, I had authorization/authentication and everything else I wanted to do was a breeze. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be reproducible as I have to randomly pair and unpair while starting and stopping the sample solution to get this prompt. I don't entirely remember what was happening when it popped up, but it does not seem easy to recreate. I thought that pairing would be my solution, but I am now stuck. When I pair with the device, I cannot access any services, but when I am unpaired, I can see all of the services and characteristics I need. However, when trying to subscribe to those characteristics I get "System.Exception: 'The attribute requires authentication before it can be read or written. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650005)'." Is there any way for me to request access to the notifications on my iPhone using something in the documentation? I need a reproducible way to request system notification access on my iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried the official [BluetoothLE sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE)?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hi, I am sorry for the late response, finals kept me busy. I have tried the official example and I am able to initiate pairing using the sample but when I try to connect to said device (A virtual peripheral advertised by my iPhone using LightBlue) I get an error saying that it has failed to connect.
isPaired true,
isConnected false,
isConnectable false. I should also add that my end goal is not to connect to a virtual peripheral but to connect to the iPhone itself. Is there any way I can get the iPhone to begin advertising itself using a UWP such as service solicitation.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the detailed message when you failed to connect your iphone when using the BLE sample? You should be able to check that by adding a breaking point in the connecting method.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Big success! I am still new so I realized I had some fatal errors. I had accidentally opened the C++ version so it was a lot more confusing for me to digest than the C# version which I was much more familiar with. I also forgot to clean and rebuild the solution which was probably the source of all my errors with faulty imports and references (I honestly don't even know how this ran the first time). However, my success was short-lived as the example has helped me understand why I have not been able to find the characteristics I am looking for. See edit I am going to add now!

Comment: So what's the real problem? Do you mean you want to communicate to your BLE device when it is already paired to other devices?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I need way to communicate with BLE devices when paired, it seems like when I pair them using the sample I am not able to access any of the services and get "Device Unreachable," however this seems to work when the device is not paired but I am not able to access any characteristics as they all require authorization.

Comment: I'm a little confused now. Let's make the question a little bit clear. When your iPhone is paired with your Windows device, then your UWP client will failed to connect to the iPhone when you call the `BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync` method. Is that right?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Exactly. This returns "Device Unreachable," and if my iPhone were to not be paired, I would have access to all of the services but would not be able to interact with any characteristics because I am not "authorized." Interestingly enough, this issue does not occur when I pair using the system settings so I think I will just scrap in app pairing as it is not my main focus.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I feel like my last comment didn't explain enough. When I pair with the "BLE" device (think windows treats the BLE and classic differently), I get device unreachable when connecting. However, when I am not paired, I can connect and see all the services and characteristics but when I try to subscribe I get "attribute requires authentication." When I mess around with pairing and unpairing for hours I will eventually get a prompt on my iPhone to share notifications (ANCS) and everything after will work. Is there a way initiate "authentication/authorization?"

Comment: Sorry to spam but just to add on the error does not occur in `BluetoothLEDevice.FromIDAsync` but rather the result of `GetGattServicesAsync` is not a success so it notifies the user "Device Unreachable" I think

Comment: So actually the `FromIDAsync` method gets the BluetoothLEDevice correctly, right? But when you are trying to query for services using `GetGattServicesAsync`, it returns "device unreachable" error, is that right? And if you are not paired, you could get the service but failed to perform Read/Write operations on a characteristic, right?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Exactly. One extra thing that I have noticed is that when I pair, Windows will create two separate Bluetooth devices in my settings, I'm assuming one is for classic Bluetooth and one is for Bluetooth low energy. One will usually be connected and paired and the other will just be paired. Also I think trying to use the in-app pairing to pair with my LightBlue virtual peripheral will actually pair with the iPhone's BLE services correctly as that has had the highest rate of success when trying to connect friend's phones.